# Find the smallest element in a list of list

Tags: python, list

Given the following list:

```
f = [[1, 19], [1, 19], [1, 19], [2, 18], [16, 4], [10, 10]]
```

I want to get the smallest value of each sub-list and create:

```
f1 = [1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 10]
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since it's a Python list, you can use `min` function for each sub-list using **list-comprehension**

```py
[min(subList) for subList in f]
```

**OUTPUT**:

```py
[1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 10]
```

Or, you can even combine `min` and `map` together

```py
list(map(min,f))
```

Answer (score 9):

An easy `numpy` way would be to use `axis=1` with `np.min`:

```
>>> f1 = np.min(f, axis =1) 
>>> f1
array([ 1,  1,  1,  2,  4, 10])
```

A non-`numpy` way could be to map `min` to `f`:

```
>>> list(map(min, f))
[1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 10]
```

Answer (score 7):

you can use builtin min function

```
f = [[1, 19], [1, 19], [1, 19], [2, 18], [16, 4], [10, 10]]
f1 = []
for i in f:
    f1.append(min(i))
f1
```